# Solve the equation: $ 3^{2x+1}+4 \cdot 3^x = 15 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Solve the equation: $ 3^{2x+1}+4 \cdot 3^x = 15 $ where $x$ is a real number.

Background: Doing Olympiad question and got one from the book.

Attempt:

Let $3^x$ be $u$.

\begin{align*}
3^{2x+1} + 4 \cdot 3x - 15 &= 0 \\
3^{2x} \cdot 3^1 + 4 \cdot 3^x - 15 &= 0 \\
3^{2x} \cdot 3 + 4 \cdot 3^x - 15 &= 0 \\
3 \cdot 3^{2x} + 4 \cdot 3^x - 15 &= 0 \\
3u^2 + 4u - 15 &= 0
\end{align*}

Factoring the equation we get

$$ u=\frac{5}{3} $$

(We eliminate $u=-3$ as $x$ is real.)

$$ 3^x=\frac{5}{3} $$

Taking $\log$ both sides

$$ x \log 3 = \log\left(\frac{5}{3}\right) $$

Now I want to know how to further solve this. Also is there any easier way to solve this?

Comment: It's not $3(0.5)=1.5$, but $3^{0.5}\approx1.7$

Comment: @Andrei that's a typo I did while solving in notebook but thanks I have removed that part now / +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

You want to find value of $x$

It can be proceeded as

$x\log3=\log(\frac{5}{3})$

$x=\frac{\log(\frac{5}{3})}{\log3}$

$x=\log_3(\frac{5}{3})$ by converse of base change theorem

$x=\log_3 5-1$

To make your solution short by two or three steps take $\log_3()$ on both sides

$3^x=5/3$

$\log_3 3^x=\log_3 (5/3)$

$x=\log_3(5/3)$

$x=\frac{\log 5 - \log 3}{\log3}$

$x=\frac{0.698 - 0.477}{0.477}$

$x=\frac{0.221}{0.477}$ which can nearly be approximated to $0.5$

Comment: @JitendraSingh can you please tell which part of question do you want to solve without use of logarithms

Comment: @JitendraSingh It seems as if you are asking how to find the value of $\log_{3} 5$. If so, you may add it in the question body.

Comment: One minute I got it thanks I will accept it soon just can you tell like is there any way to solve the original question without log?

Comment: @soupless and the answer writer at first I needed it but soon I remembered the identity to compute it and I no more need it

Comment: @JitendraSingh I can't think of some other solution than what you wrote in your attempt. To solve it you have to make it a quadratic and then substitute $3^x$ as $u$ and then to get $x$ down you have to use $\log ()$

Comment: @LalitTolani its fine Thanks for the help I have accepted your answer now

Comment: @JitendraSingh Wait I have something to tell you. you can factorize it as $3^x(3^{x+1}+4)=3*5=1*15$ and then check if it holds for an integral value of x but that will require time as if you can't get satisfying results from this you again have to indulge in substitution and logarithms

Comment: @JitendraSingh I would solve this equation exactly like you did (and follow it by Lalit Tolani's continuation). This is a pretty standard way to solve such equations and is very easy to do (you only have to notice how to convert it into a quadratic equation, and the rest is simple technique). I'm pretty sure this is the easiest way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

$$3^{2x+1}+4\cdot 3^x=15
\\3\cdot(3^x)^2+4\cdot 3^x=15$$
let $u=3^x$:
$$3u^2+4u-15=0$$
solve the quadratic then you have:
$$x_{1,2}=\log_3(u_{1,2})$$

Answer (score 0):

It depends. It seems as if you already have a short solution and you may consider taking base-$3$ logarithm to make a shorter one, but most of the time, logarithms are of base-$e$, which is exactly what you did.